# How to SSH apache user from a remote guest server on VirtualBox with host-only network?

Tags: networking, centos, ssh, virtualbox, apache-1.3

I have two CentOS virtual machines on VirtualBox . one of them let's say CentOS-1 holds my Web application code . second is CentOS2 . 
I have two network connections between these two servers : Bridged & Host-only .

> **CentOS-1** : for Bridged connection the ip is : 192.168.0.137 
>              for  Host-only connection the ip is : 192.168.1.137
>
> **CentOS-2** : for Bridged connection the ip is : 192.168.0.101 
>              for  Host-only connection the ip is : 192.168.1.101

in my php web page when I try to ssh like this :

```
 exec('ssh -p 22 root@192.168.0.101 2>&1 ',$output);
```

it's working , but when I'm trying to ssh to the host-only network ip  :

```
 exec('ssh -p 22 root@192.168.1.101 2>&1 ',$output);
```

I got this as an output :

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.101 port 22: No route to host
```

I tried to re-generate public key for 192.168.0.137 and copy it to 192.168.0.101 but it didn't help . I also tried to give privileges to apache user :

on CentOS-2 :
    sudo -u apache ssh root@192.168.1.137 "pwd"
    sudo -u apache ssh root@192.168.0.137 "pwd"

on CentOS-1 :

```
sudo -u apache ssh root@192.168.1.101 "pwd"     
sudo -u apache ssh root@192.168.0.101 "pwd"
```

neither of the two ways worked . is there any thing that I has missed ? 
The output of ifconfig -a :

```
$ ifconfig -a                                                                                                     
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:0B:56:0E                                                                               
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0                                                            
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe0b:560e/64 Scope:Link                                                                          
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                                                                          
          RX packets:5652 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                                       
          TX packets:4886 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                                     
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                                                                                                
          RX bytes:833395 (813.8 KiB)  TX bytes:769122 (751.0 KiB)                                                                    

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:FA:C6:32                                                                               
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                                                                                     
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                                          
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                                        
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                                                                                                
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)                                                                                      

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback                                                                                                   
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0                                                                                         
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host                                                                                              
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1                                                                                    
          RX packets:6315 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                                       
          TX packets:6315 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                                     
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                                                                                   
          RX bytes:878894 (858.2 KiB)  TX bytes:878894 (858.2 KiB)
```

and output of route :

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth1 inet 192.168.1.101 broadcast 192.168.1.255 netmask 255.255.255.0 up                          
[sudo] password for safaa:                                                                                                            

    [safaa@AMeS101 ~]$ route                                                                                                           
Kernel IP routing table                                                                                                               
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface                                                         
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1                                                          
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0                                                          
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0                                                          
default         mbox.kds.local  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please give output of "ifconfig -a" and "route" commands on one or both of the CentOS guests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the answer : 
**on CentOS1 :**

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.191 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

sudo touch /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 

 sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1  

DEVICE="eth1"
IPADDR=192.168.1.191
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"

sudo ifup eth1
```

on **CentOS1** who ssh to this server:

```
sudo -u apache ssh root@192.168.1.191"pwd"
```

then apache can ssh to 192.168.1.191 and you can do whatever you want :)

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be a few things you will need to do.

Asuming that pinging one machine to the other results in the same error, try to run this command. [Setting up a route](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/)

```
route
```

You will most likly not see any rules for that. Assuming you have setup the ip addresses in the correct files [centos netowkring info](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-networkscripts.html)

```
/etc/sysconfig/network
```

once both the network and route are setup you should be able to talk together. To test if someone is not sending data back tcpdump is your friend. [Tcpdump help](http://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/)